# Solving an Inequality Constrained optimization Equation in R or Python

Tags: python, r, nonlinear-optimization, inequality

I have the following model for system of linear equations. I want to solve for `beta_i_j` on a grid of `residuals_i` between bounds. I want neither `b_estimate` nor `residuals` to get negative.

```
Y_i = X_i_j * beta_i_j + residuals_i

i=1,2,....N => N = 10,000
j=1,2,....M => M = 500
```

`Y_i` is known (float variable)
`X_i_j` is known (integer variable)
`residuals_i` is unknown (float variable)
`beta_i_j` are unknown and are decision variables

Objective Function:

```
residuals_i = Y_i - X_i_j * beta_i_j >=0
```

subject to:

```
beta_i_j > 0
0 <= residuals_i < max(Y_i)
```

In the end, I am expecting to get distribution of `beta_i_j` between `residuals_i` bounds `(0, max(Y_i))`

Would be very grateful if you guys can help or give me a hint to solve this in R or Python.

Thanks a bunch :-).

Comment: This problem formulation does not make sense. You have several objective functions $residuals_i, i = 1,...n$. Are you looking for a [pareto-frontier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency#Pareto_frontier)?

Comment: minimize sum of prediction errors in a linear regression, based on constraint of positive parameters, and positive errors -> based on your data; this might make sense, but I am kind of hesitant about the posing of the problem which practically forces bias. Anyway, your way to go should be implemented in linear solvers of scipy.optimize

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. @Uvar yes i want to enforce bias because Y_i is actually inflated with some unknown i.e. residuals that are not negative. Can you please tell me how I put a constraint in scipy.optimize for only positive residuals e.g. residuals > 0? Thanks